# Cannot send mails via outlook through java application

Tags: java, email, outlook

Have the following mail configuration settings :

```
mail.smtp.host=smtp.us.deloitte.com
mail.smtp.socketFactory.port=25
mail.smtp.socketFactory.class=javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory
mail.smtp.auth=true
mail.smtp.port=25
```

and the following properties :

```
mail.password=password
mail.from=sam@xyz.com
mail.to=sam@xyz.com
mail.subject=Status of Data pushed
```

I get the following error :

java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.us.deloitte.com, port: 25;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.SocketException: Permission denied:

The same code when I use gmail as the 'from' account and the Outlook account in 'to', it works.

I tried setting setx _JAVA_OPTIONS -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true, also disabled iPv6 on Windows 7 box, but nothing seems to work

Comment: Is this connection going through a proxy? Has your IP address been added to your company firewall? Default port for `SMTPS` is `465` or `587` and not `25`.

Comment: Make sure you turn on same at Gmail, turn on lesssecureapps https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps
i dont know about outLook

Answer (score 0):

*Just an observation:* You are using [STMPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SMTPS) protocol, and most SMTPS servers still communicates on the deprecated port `465` or the standardized [port 587](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6409) and not `25`.

Comment: I was using 465 port for gmail, but for my Microsoft outlook account, I asked the network department who responded saying the smtp port no it uses is 25.

Comment: Then they're not using SMTPS but SMTP protocol.